# Vue resource, using the same form for inserts and updates

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm using Vue resource to connect to my backend api.  I have a form component which I use for both creating a new resource item and modifying existing resource items.  The form works fine, but when I want to save the form, it needs to use the proper http method for the api call.  If I am creating a new item, it should use the `POST` method, and if I'm updating an existing item it should use the `PUT` method.  Right now, my form save method looks something like this:

```js
    if (this.itemId > 0) {   // Update existing item
        myresource.update({id: this.itemId}, this.item).then(response => {
            //...
        }, response => {
            //...
        });
    }
    else {      // Post new item
        myresource.save({}, this.item).then(response => {
            //...
        }, response => {
            //...
        });
    }
```

Basically, I have to use an `if` statement to check whether to use the `update` or `save` resource functions, then the success/fail promises both use the same code.  Is there some way to combine the two methods above with something like this:

```js
    var method = this.itemId ? 'PUT' : 'POST';
    myresource.request(method, {id: this.itemId}, this.item).then(response => {
            //...
        }, response => {
            //...
        });
```

The above code obviously doesn't work, but is there a similar way to accomplish this without using an `if` statement and repeating my success/fail promises for each request type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple option would be to create the request based on the conditions and then connect the remaining promises in a single chain:

```js
    const request = (this.itemId > 0) ? myresource.update ? myresource.save;
    request({
      id: this.itemId // Make the save call ignore the id
    }, this.item).then(response => {
      // Shared code
    });
```

Comment: This looks like it should do nicely.  Thanks!